# how to get source and destination latitude and longitude?

Tags: android

hi all how to implement code for getting latitude and longitude when we enter the location address (i mean when i enter from address and to address into auto complete Textview.then i will get the latitude and longitude for from address and to address).so help me solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for reverse Geo coding concept. And it is well explained here.

http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
>     android:layout_height="fill_parent">
>  
>     <com.google.android.maps.MapView 
>         android:id="@+id/mapView"
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>         android:enabled="true"
>         android:clickable="true"
>         android:apiKey="0l4sCTTyRmXTNo7k8DREHvEaLar2UmHGwnhZVHQ"
>         />
>  
> </RelativeLayout>
>
>
>      
> import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
> import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
> import com.google.android.maps.MapView.LayoutParams;  
>  
> import android.os.Bundle;
> import android.view.View;
> import android.widget.LinearLayout;
>  
> public class MapsActivity extends MapActivity 
> {    
>     MapView mapView; 
>  
>     /** Called when the activity is first created. */
>     @Override
>     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
>     {
>         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>         setContentView(R.layout.main);
>  
>  
>         mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
>         LinearLayout zoomLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.zoom);  
>         View zoomView = mapView.getZoomControls(); 
>  
>         zoomLayout.addView(zoomView, 
>             new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
>                 LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
>                 LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 
>         mapView.displayZoomControls(true);
>  
>     }
>  
>     @Override
>     protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
>         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>         return false;
>     }
> }
> ```